# JUnit test for Java servlet: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit

I'm new to JUnit test and I tried to create my first JUnit test using a sample JUnit test. But, I keep getting the above exception. Below is my JUnit test code.

```
package iworks;

import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Unit tests for {@link StudentTimelineJobsServlet}.
 */
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class StudentTimelineJobsServletTest {
  private static final String FAKE_URL = "fake.fk/hello";
  // Set up a helper so that the ApiProxy returns a valid environment for local testing.
  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper();

  @Mock private HttpServletRequest mockRequest;
  @Mock private HttpServletResponse mockResponse;
  private StringWriter responseWriter;
  private StudentTimelineJobsServlet servletUnderTest;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    helper.setUp();

    //  Set up some fake HTTP requests
    when(mockRequest.getRequestURI()).thenReturn(FAKE_URL);

    // Set up a fake HTTP response.
    responseWriter = new StringWriter();
    when(mockResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(new PrintWriter(responseWriter));

    servletUnderTest = new StudentTimelineJobsServlet();
  }

  @After public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void doGetWritesResponse() throws Exception {
    servletUnderTest.doGet(mockRequest, mockResponse);// The error occurs at this line

    // assertThat(responseWriter.toString())
        // .named("StudentTimelineJobsServlet response")
        // .contains("Jobs fetched successfully!");
  }
}
```

The error occurs at the line indicated above, and I don't understand why I'm getting null pointer exception because `servletUnderTest` has already been initialized. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Below is the stack trace of the error:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.334 s <<< FAILURE! - in iworks.StudentTimelineJobsServletTest
[ERROR] doGetWritesResponse(iworks.StudentTimelineJobsServletTest)  Time elapsed: 0.329 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at iworks.StudentTimelineJobsServletTest.doGetWritesResponse(StudentTimelineJobsServletTest.java:60)

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   StudentTimelineJobsServletTest.doGetWritesResponse:60 » NullPointer
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23.845 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-09T18:40:51-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project iworks: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Semeredin\IdeaProjects\SWE_Project\iWorks\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project iworks: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\Semeredin\IdeaProjects\SWE_Project\iWorks\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\Semeredin\IdeaProjects\SWE_Project\iWorks\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.throwException (SurefireHelper.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (SurefireHelper.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePlugin.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:937)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Below is my StudentTimelineJobsServlet class code:

```
package iworks;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet(name = "StudentTimelineJobsServlet", value = "/jobs")
public class StudentTimelineJobsServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Extract the pool from the Servlet Context, reusing the one that was created
    // in the ContextListener when the application was started
    DataSource pool = (DataSource) req.getServletContext().getAttribute("my-pool");

    List<OpportunityPost> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = pool.getConnection()) {
      // PreparedStatements are compiled by the database immediately and executed at a later date.
      // Most databases cache previously compiled queries, which improves efficiency.
      PreparedStatement jobsStmt =  conn.prepareStatement(
          "SELECT title, institution, period, location, description, link FROM jobs");
      // Execute the statement
      ResultSet jobsResults = jobsStmt.executeQuery();
      // Convert a ResultSet into OpportunityPost objects
      while (jobsResults.next()) {
        String title = jobsResults.getString(1);
        String institution = jobsResults.getString(2);
        String period = jobsResults.getString(3);
        String location = jobsResults.getString(4);
        String description = jobsResults.getString(5);
        String link = jobsResults.getString(6);
        jobs.add(new OpportunityPost(title, institution, period, location, description, link));
      }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      // If something goes wrong, the application needs to react appropriately. This might mean
      // getting a new connection and executing the query again, or it might mean redirecting the
      // user to a different page to let them know something went wrong.
      throw new ServletException("Unable to successfully connect to the database. Please try again.", ex);
    }

    // Add variables and render the page
    req.setAttribute("jobs", jobs);
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Jobs fetched successfully!");
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/studentTimelineJobs.jsp").forward(req, resp);
  }
}
```

Comment: please post stacktrace

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I just did.

Comment: Does StudentTimelineJobsServlet have dependencies?

Comment: @FelipeBonfante I just shared the StudentTimelineJobsServlet class code

Comment: @FelipeBonfante it's a maven project by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In your doGet method you have:

```
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    //....
    DataSource pool = (DataSource) req.getServletContext().getAttribute("my-pool");
    //....
    resp.getWriter().println("Jobs fetched successfully!");
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/studentTimelineJobs.jsp").forward(req, resp);
  }
```

What do you think the mock objects `HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp` will return when you call `getSomething()` on them without setting what these mocks should return in such case? They will return `null`, this is the cause of the NPE, you need to record proper behavior at least for these calls listed in the snippet above.